# How to display RSS feed images in DetailViewController IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, rss

I am displaying cinema gossips in UITableview then select the cell its displays Detailviewcontroller . Successfully Get the data in UITableview, In DetailviewController UIImageview and UITextview, Get the Description Successfully but Images not displayed. This is my code please check once's

This is URL `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cinejosh.com/rss-feed/3/andhra-latest-gossips-news.html"];`

This is my code. IS any problem in my code. please check once's

```
- (void)loadingImageUrl 
{

    NSData *gossipsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:gossipsUrl];
    TFHpple *gossipsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:gossipsHtmlData];
    NSString *gossipsXpathQueryString = @"//td//img";
    imageGossipsNodes = [gossipsParser searchWithXPathQuery:gossipsXpathQueryString];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in imageGossipsNodes) {

        NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.cinejosh.com%@", [element objectForKey:@"src"]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}
```

Its doesn't call for loop.

Comment: Sorry this my URL  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cinejosh.com/rss-feed/4/telugu.html"];

Comment: TFHppleElement is not an Array it is NSObject